# Get values of select with same name Jquery?

Tags: jquery, json

I have this 
**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control" required="" name="article">
<option value="Coca Cola">Coca Cola</option>
<option value="Carnex">Carnex</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" required="" name="article">
<option value="Fanta">Fanta</option>
<option value="Sprite">Sprite</option>
</select>
```

What i need is to get value of selects and make a new json like this

```
var articlesSelected =
[{
  "article" : "Coca Cola"
},{
  "article" : "Fanta"
}
];


var selects = array();
selects = $('[name~=article]').val();
```

Comment: And where is your javascript?

Comment: BTW, there's no function `array()` in JS. That's PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `$.each()` at this context to accomplish your task elegantly,

```
var articlesSelected = $.map($('select[name="article"]'), function (val, _) {
    var newObj = {};
    newObj.article = val.value;
    return newObj;
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jhytcxgr/)

Answer (score 2):

`.val()` only returns the value of the first element in the collection. You need to use `.each()` or [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/):

```
var selects = $('[name=article]').map(function() { 
    return { article: this.value };
}).get();
```

Comment: Using .map() would costs two iterations one for the mapping and the other one is to convert the same into an array. So $.map() would be efficient. Am i right.? :)

Comment: There's only one iteration. It's returning an array wrapped in a jQuery object, and `.get()` simply removes the wrapper.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy No. `.get()` will internally `return slice.call(this)`, which does what Barmar mentions.

Answer (score 0):

Ah! You can do that like this:

```
var articles = $('select').map(function(){ return $(this).val() }).get();
var json = JSON.stringify([{article:articles[0]},{article:articles[1]}]);
```